# Nginx config with wordpress in a subfolder and alias

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a pretty weird nginx setup. I need the following setup:

- url "/" -> static html files in /srv/www/landing-pages
- url "/tr_tr/blog/*" -> wordpress installation in /srv/www/domain.com
- url "/en_us/blog/*" -> wordpress installation in /srv/www/domain.com

The wordpress configuration is like

- currently the wordpress installation is configured to answer to domain.com.
- the whole /tr_tr/blog structure is constructed with wpml multi language plugin.
- two wordpress pages are created with "/blog" slug and are prefixed with locales by the wpml plugin.
- Blog post permalinks are set to /blog/%postname%-%post_id%/ Those permalinks are prefixed with locales by wpml automatically too.

My nginx configuration is

```
server {
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/xml
        text/css
        image/svg+xml
        application/json
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)”;

    expires $expires;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;

    server_tokens off;

#    include /etc/nginx/nginx-wp-common.conf;

location / {
  root /srv/www/landing-pages;
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri;
}

location /tr_tr/blog {
  alias /srv/www/domain.com/;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;

  location ~ \/tr_tr\/blog\/.*\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/domain.com/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }

 }
}
```

I added only tr_tr location during development. Currently I'm getting 404's 403's "No input file specified's" for blog urls.

Root urls are fine, I can open my dummy html files in srv/www/landing-pages folder from domain.com/test.html

The idea is,

- all urls should follow /{locale}/{project} template.
- corporate landing pages will be served from landing-pages folder (gatsbyjs)
- Company blog is served from /{locale}/blog urls
- I dont want to create two seperate wp installations for both countries.

How can I setup this configuration in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! This is the scenario (my case):

- symfony: /var/www/mysite.com
- wp: /var/www/blog.mysite.com

And this is how you access (replace example for mysite because validation)

- symfony: https://example.com
- wp: https://example.com/blog

This is my default.conf

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/web;

    location @wp {
        rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blog/index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ^~ /blog {
        alias /var/www/blog.mysite.com;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name mysite.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```